# Proving $\lfloor e^x \rfloor =\lfloor e^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \rfloor$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove that  $$\lfloor e^x \rfloor =\lfloor  e^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \rfloor \tag{1}$$

I was actually trying to prove $$\lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor=\lfloor \sqrt{\lfloor x \rfloor} \rfloor$$ and i succeeded since i started with:

$$\lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor =m$$ and I have seen a generalized result:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous increasing function , Then $\lfloor f(\lfloor x\rfloor)\rfloor=\lfloor f(x)\rfloor.$

In similar manner i started trying to prove $(1)$

$$\lfloor e^x \rfloor=m$$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$

Case $1.$ If $x \lt 0$, Then we have $0 \lt e^x \lt 1$ Hence $$\lfloor e^x \rfloor=0$$

Also when $x \lt 0$, We have $\lfloor x \rfloor \lt 0$ $\implies$ $0 \lt e^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \lt 1$

Hence $$\lfloor  e^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \rfloor=0$$

Case $2.$ If $x \ge 0$, Then $m \ge 1$

Letting $$\lfloor e^x \rfloor=m$$
We have

$$m \le e^x \lt m+1$$ $\implies$

$$\ln(m) \le x \lt \ln(m+1)$$

How to proceed from here?

Comment: $e^{1.9}=6.68...$ yet $2 \neq 6$.

Comment: Yeah, this inequality is false.

Comment: For $x$ in what set?

Comment: This is clearly not true, for instance $x=\ln(3)=1.09...$ you have 
$\lfloor e^{\ln(3)}\rfloor=\lfloor 3\rfloor=3$. On the other hand, you have
$\lfloor e^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\rfloor=\lfloor e^1\rfloor=2.$

Comment: Whenever you want to prove something it's *always* a good idea to start by testing it for simple cases to get a feel for whats going on. In this case almost any example will show it's wrong.

Comment: Yes my bad. but i have taken the generalized result grantedly. Whats wrong in the result?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  $f(x)=e^x$ is STILL a counterexample of your edited claim in the pink box.

Comment: The generalized result is also false, since it is false for $f(x)=e^x.$ What you have with $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is the property that $f(x)$ is an integer only when $x$ is an integer, and it is increasing, and $f(x+1)-f(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\geq 0.$

Comment: Oh i am so sorry, please have a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930093/proving-lfloor-f-lfloor-x-rfloor-rfloor-lfloor-fx-rfloor

Comment: Yeah, there's a crucial hypothesis there, succinctly:  $f^{-1}(\mathbb{Z}) \subset \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: That's a completely different question.

Comment: I beg my pardon, I misunderstood the linked thread problem. Now i understood that its applicable only for functions satisfying when $f(x)$ is an integer, $x$ must be an integer and $f(x)$ is continuous and increasing function over $R$